# Groups - simple properties and conclusion.

Tags: group-theory

The Set $G$ is group with $\oplus$ and neutral element $e$. It implies that:
**a.** for each $a\in G$ we have $a\oplus e = a$.
**b.** for $a,b\in G$ we have that $a\oplus b = b\oplus a$.
**c.** set $G$ can't contain exactly $2015$ elements.

**My approach**
**a.** is true, from definition of group.
**b.** is true, fairly obvious
**c.** is false, for example $Z_{2015}$.

What about my answers. Correct ?

Comment: $b)$ is only true, if $G$ is abelian. The other answers are correct.

Comment: Yes, I meant that **b** is false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About your answers:

**a.** Correct.

**b.** Incorrect, as you confirm in the comments. Consider giving a counterexample.

**c.** Correct.